# How to show TXT or ASCII file into UIWebView correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to show `TXT file (ASCII)` into `UIVewView`. For example, using the site [www.partisani.net/35.txt](http://www.partisani.net/35.txt) in Safari on MacBook works fine, Safari on iPhone doesn't. Safari's iPhone shows the file with another layout. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by «another layout»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the layout of the file on the Mac vs iOS is exactly the same.  Are you talking about text wrapping?  You can see that on the Mac by resizing the browser.

If you want to handle the line length differently you'll need to do so by setting up scrolling.

UPDATE with more detail:

This "sort of" changes the original content :).  Basically, you need to tweak both the contentSize of the webview and embed the text file in some boilerplate HTML to reflow the text rather than have the default viewport width assigned to the text document.  The latter I accomplish with something like:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.partisani.net/35.txt"];
UIWebView* vw = (UIWebView*)self.view;
vw.delegate = self;

NSData* Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString* aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString* responseStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<HTML>"
                         "<head>"
                         "<title>Text View</title>"
                         "</head>"
                         "<BODY>"
                         "<pre>"
                         "%@"
                         "/pre>"
                         "</BODY>"
                         "</HTML>",
                         aStr];
[vw loadHTMLString:responseStr baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
[aStr release];
```

The `vw.delegate = self` is important, as you also need to have your controller conform to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method.  There you can set the scroll width and height of your webview as needed:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {    
     UIScrollView* sview = (UIScrollView*)[[webview subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
     sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 800);
}
```

This is an extremely barebones implementation--presumably you would also want logic to calculate the necessary width and height based upon the loaded text rather than use constants as shown here; you'll need some parsing logic associated with the original data for that, but this should get you started.

Comment: Text wrapping, exactly. See [link](http://www.partisani.net/wrapping.jpg) please!

Comment: Right. So you'll need to change the contentSize of the web view to allow the width to exceed the visible viewpane.

Comment: And/or use css to make the text look the way you want - i.e. look at not loading the text file, but making a new file or data object with the text in a div, then render that.. you can find lots of nice looking text rendndered on the web.

Comment: jstevenco, How can I do this? I'm sorry but I'm new in Xcode programming? Can you help me please?

Comment: Thanks you Tom, but I can't change the html file!

Comment: Good idea, jstevenco! I also replaced 'new line' with '<BR>' ([[aStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"<BR>"]]) and the result is excellent (without webViewDidFinishLoad delegate)! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the scalesPageToFit property to yes might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is actually something to do with TXT or ASCII, but rather the UIWebview resizing the content.

The file you mentioned loaded into a landscape ipad screen has exactly the same layout as on Mac Safari:

[image]

You can change whether or not the UIWebView scales its content with the scalesPageToFit property.

Comment: what is the frame of the webview used in that screenshot, and did you try changing the value of the webview's scalesPageToFit property ?